# Trouble with Devise validation styling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I am using the Devise gem for a user login page and user registration pages on a basic Ruby on Rails app. **I want to get rid of the ugly default styling for when there is an error.** I was able to replace the error box with some bootstrap styling, but I can't find any answers about how to get rid of the ugly red boxes that appear around my inputs and my input labels. **Also, the inputs are shrinking when validation occurs.** They start at 100% width. Then, if there is an error,they shrink. Here is an image of both problems. The input box should be as wide as the .danger div above:

[image]

Here is the code for this page:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="top col-md-4 col-md-push-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-push-1">
<div class="logo_container">
  <%= image_tag "musilogopurple.png", class: 'logo_big' %> 
</div>
<p class="text-center">Forget your password? Enter your email below and we will send you reset instructions.</p>
<br />

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <br />
    <%= f.submit "Send", class: 'btn btn-purple'%>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
</div>
```

I would very much appreciate some guidance. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you scaffold anything? Scaffolds bring in CSS files try deleting those if you're not using it. In addition, it would help if you posted the CSS files it's receiving styling from.

Comment: You are very wise sir! Yes, the problem was in my scaffold styling. Specifically, this code was causing the problem:

.field_with_errors {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  display: table;
}